# How to ? In c# getting throw error i want to check the value from method body

Tags: c#, asp.net

1.In c#.
2.Following is the seudo code
 of my c# program :
Following

```
class example{
    boolean a=false,b=false;
    Protected method1(){
        a=true
    }
    Protected method2(){
        b=true
    }
    if(a && b){
        execute block
    }
    else{
        thorw error
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: do you mean throwing error via code, if yes, then : `throw new Exception("error thrown");`